# Serving port 443 over http creates 400 Bad Request Error instead of redirect

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, http

So for posterity sake, I am trying to configure my server so that even when someone tries to go to go to http:// domain.com:443, they would be correctly redirected to the https version of the site (https:// domain.com).

When testing something like http:// domain.com:443, it does not redirect correctly to https:// domain.com, I instead get hit with a 400 Bad Request page with the following content:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
>   Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
>
> Apache/2.4.18  (Ubuntu) Server at sub.domain.com Port 443

I tried including the following lines in my `000-default.conf` in the `<VirtualHost *:80>`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

But it didn't work.

This issue occurs on all domains, subdomains and the server IP itself.

Possibly related, trying to do a dry run of letsencrypt returns the following:

```
   Domain: domain.com
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Failed to connect to 123.123.123.123:443 for TLS-SNI-01
   challenge
```

For each and every domain listed in the sites-enabled folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;TR: you cannot serve both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port (443).

While it would be in theory possible to figure out based on the first data from the client if the client is sending a HTTP request (i.e. `GET ..` or similar) or is starting a TLS handshake (`\x16\x03...`) most web servers don't do this. Instead they expect the client to behave properly, that is use plain HTTP on one port (usually 80) and HTTPS on another port (usually 443).

Your URL of `http://example.com:443` is causing the browser to make a plain HTTP request to port 443. But the server is expecting TLS there which means that your plain HTTP request is unexpected. Apache is at least nice enough to check if the incoming data for a plain HTTP request in this case so that it can offer you a more useful description:

> Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port. Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

If you try such requests with other servers then they would either close the connection without any error at all or just hang because they are still hoping to get a TLS handshake from the client.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Though- I understand the difference, I'm not trying to server :443 over http, I'm trying to force a redirect when the user tries to invoke 443 on a http url.

EDIT: The reason I am even trying to do this is because I've seen other web hosts handle these weird connections properly.

Comment: nginx also returns a 400 Bad Request error, stating: "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"

Comment: Is there any way to maybe even throw a 301 up instead of the 400 error? I know it's probably a bit hacky... But I still want to mitigate the issue.

Comment: @Bitz Why do you want to do this?!

Comment: Because it seems pretty standard. Most websites I tested this on worked fine and I want to be able to measure to up that, I guess, haha. 
(And I'm sure those who come across this page in a year or two would want an answer)

Comment: @Bitz: " I'm not trying to server :443 over http, I'm trying to force a redirect when the user tries to invoke 443 on a http url. " - A redirect is done with HTTP. Sou you want to serve your own HTTP response if the client accesses HTTP on the HTTPS port and that's exactly what the server will not allow you.

Comment: @Bitz: "..Because it seems pretty standard. Most websites I tested this on worked fine..":  I don't know what you've tried but: google.com and facebook.com just close the connection (don't try with a browser, because of HSTS they will only use https for these sites), arstechnica.com and baidu.com give error 400, microsoft.com and outlook.com hang and yandex.com interestingly returns a 200 response. None of these returns a 301. Thus 301 does not look like a standard behavior at all for me.

Comment: @Bitz this is something nginx will let you do, see 
https://serverfault.com/questions/338700/redirect-http-example-com12345-to-https-example-com12345-in-nginx (they defined an internal response code 497 you can catch to redirect the user)
I arrived here trying to know if Apache can do the same, the answer seems to be no according to your exchanges, even though it knows it's this situation.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same error and the culprit was that my config was trying to enable SSL on my non-ssl port. Any website address that starts with `http://` will be funneled through port 80 (`<VirtualHost *:80>`) and that host doesn't want to know anything about SSL. Any sites that start with `https://` will be funneled through port 443 (`<VirtualHost *:443>`)

The more direct issue was that I had the following SSL details under my `*:80` host, which was making Apache try to enable SSL for a non-SSL connection.

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /bla.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /bla.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /bla.crt
```

After removing those lines from `*:80` (and making sure they were present under `<VirtualHost *:443>`) My server popped back up again.

So, here are my `<VirtualHost>`s (all in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/http.conf` but might be different depending on your setup):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    -- snip --

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

    -- snip --

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/ssl/STAR_iconcierge_net_au.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/ssl/STAR_iconcierge_net_au.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/ssl/STAR_iconcierge_net_au.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Notice how `*:80` (http) enacts a rewrite to `*:443` (https), which then enforces SSL with the `SSLEngine on` directive.

Comment: Removing the first 4 lines worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

What you are actually looking after is sending HSTS headers from the webserver back to the users, which tell the browser always to access the site using TLS. There isn't any `301` redirect happening there, as you can see from the development tools in any browser.

This happens with Google for example. Once you have visited Google the first time, it sent you a HSTS header, and your browser saved the header to a list. After, when you try to connect to `google.com` with `http://`, the browser changes the connection method automatically to `https://` without any communication to the remote webserver.

This is one further security mechanism to prevent attacks on the security layer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I strugle around the world try to solve it and finally I could make my problem solved by using this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ErrorDocument 400 "https://example.com/?error-bad-request"
</VirtualHost>
```

This will redirect your request **`http`**`://example.com:443` to **`https`**`://example.com/?error-bad-request`

Hope this works with you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that is inside the `<VirtualHost *:80>` section will be processed when you access the site using the port 443.

Test enabling the ssl version of the default site that come with apache2 and try that conf there inside `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: I tried dropping the Rewrite lines I mentioned before into the `default-ssl.conf` file and ensured the sl in _sites-enabled_ pointed to the conf. 
Restarted apache and sadly, no changes.

Comment: And you said that worked with named vhosts but not with the default unnamed vhost? Could you show the result of `ls -la site-enabled`

Comment: I thought that it was working for domains, but it seems like I was wrong and I tested it incorrectly, so the issue where http:/*:443 traffic isn't being transferred to https:// is universal for apache.

Also, here are the results of the command ls -la sites-enabled: http://i.imgur.com/UeFsWOB.png

Answer (score 0):

My http/apache configuration was

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

I changed it to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

And the problem went away....

Answer (score -1):

In my experience i just deleted code in apache2.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
#Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

and httpd-vhosts.conf first entry custom settings .
restarted and worked

Comment: This just the SSL listener at all.